# Passing the web service response from API Test to GUI Test in UFT 12.52

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft, web-api-testing

I want to achieve the following tasks:

1) Send the request

2) Validate the response

3) Use the various field in the response as an input for GUI validation of the web application.

I am stuck on the last step.

Is there any specific way to retrieve the data fields and value from the response?

Comment: Thanks Manish, can you put your comment as a Answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use input/output parameters while calling API test from GUI test and by passing values as output parameter from API to GUI test you can achieve your task.

Check `"Use API test parameters in a GUI test"` part on [**`this`**](http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/z_Ch_Integ_API_Tests.htm) link for more information.